# iOS command line tool to convert jpeg to png?

Tags: ios

I am looking for a command line tool to use in my bash script that converts a jpg image to a png one.
Thx!

edit: to be clear, the platform the script runs on is iOS. So I am looking for a binary that's compiled for the ARM plaform.

Comment: on iOS...? with command line...? what are you working on? :)

Comment: scheduled downloading of a pdf (daily local newspaper), adding it to iBooks (manipulating Purchases.plist), adding a fake .app in the newsstand that has the pdf's frontpage as Icon.png

Comment: why not just display it as a jpg?

Comment: didn't know jpegs are working as icon files. will try that then!

Comment: okay. Simply renaming it to Icon.png seemed to work fine. Thx! Will look further into ImageMagick though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned iOS, I assume you are using Mac OSX. If so, you can install ImageMagick via [Homebrew](https://mxcl.dev/homebrew/) or [MacPorts](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) and use the following command in your script

```
convert my_image.jpg my_image.png
```

ImageMagick is a powerful tool for manipulating all sorts of images. Check out the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) if you wish to go a bit more advanced

Comment: Actually, as I wrote I am working on iOS. But thanks for the hint! I found ImageMagick compiled to work on arm processor (it's even in cydia)!

Comment: Ah I assumed you were running the bash script as part of your app build process.

Comment: True. might have been the case =)  Runningin a problem thougheith ImageMagick.When I use'convert' on a jpeg I get  'convert: no decode delegate for this image format ...' Seems to be missing some jpeg libary. But I'm not sure where to find that in cydia..